# Как создать красивый логотип для консольного приложения

Tags: linux, ascii-art

как создать логотип для консольного приложения, например

```
    _____   _______ ________  ______
   /  _/ | / / ___//  _/ __ \/ ____/
   / //  |/ /\__ \ / // / / / __/
 _/ // /|  /___/ // // /_/ / /___
/___/_/ |_//____/___/_____/_____/
```

Comment: Придумай и отрисуй

Comment: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ASCII_art

Comment: с некоторой долей везения можно попытаться воспользоваться ChatGPT/Bing Chat для этого

Comment: логотип из букв - это скучно.  вот нескучный логотип: `(.)(.)`

Answer (score 6):

Это FIGlet.

Эту штуку обычно делают через программу figlet или toilet.

```
echo eri | figlet -f big.flf
           _ 
          (_)
  ___ _ __ _ 
 / _ \ '__| |
|  __/ |  | |
 \___|_|  |_|
             

echo eri | figlet -f smslant.flf
          _ 
 ___ ____(_)
/ -_) __/ / 
\__/_/ /_/
```

Установка

```
apt install toilet toilet-fonts figlet
```

`/usr/share/figlet/*.flf` - шрифты figlet, `/usr/share/figlet/*.tlf` - шрифты toilet. там ещё эффекты какие-то есть. стандартных мало - надо искать дополнительные.

Можно найти десяток онлайн сервисов, например https://patorjk.com/software/taag/#p=display&f=Bloody&t=ESC

```
▓█████   ██████  ▄████▄  
▓█   ▀ ▒██    ▒ ▒██▀ ▀█  
▒███   ░ ▓██▄   ▒▓█    ▄ 
▒▓█  ▄   ▒   ██▒▒▓▓▄ ▄██▒
░▒████▒▒██████▒▒▒ ▓███▀ ░
░░ ▒░ ░▒ ▒▓▒ ▒ ░░ ░▒ ▒  ░
 ░ ░  ░░ ░▒  ░ ░  ░  ▒   
   ░   ░  ░  ░  ░        
   ░  ░      ░  ░ ░      
                ░
```

Comment: Могу ещё добавить, что есть прикольный пакет `cowsay`.